# "Files" application says "Unable to access location, mount point does not exist" when clicking on NFS server in "Other Locations"

Tags: mount, nautilus, nfs

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I click on the "Files" application, and then I click on "Other Locations" at the bottom of the sidebar.  Among other things, it shows an NFS server on my network:

[image: Other Locations]

I click on "WhiteAndNerdy (nfs)", and this message pops up:

[image: Mount point does not exist]

What exactly does that mean, and how do I fix it?

**Updates**:

Here is what I get when I right click on "WhiteAndNerdy (nfs)":

[image: right-click menu]

Here is what I get when I run `sudo /usr/bin/journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` immediately after clicking on "WhiteAndNerdy (nfs)":

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-09-21 10:51:35 PDT, end at Thu 2021-10-14 20:13:43 PDT. --
Oct 14 20:10:36 midnight-star NetworkManager[22487]: <info>  [1634267436.6278] policy: set 'Wile E. Coyote' (wlo1) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Oct 14 20:13:13 midnight-star NetworkManager[22487]: <info>  [1634267593.7695] policy: set 'Wile E. Coyote' (wlo1) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Oct 14 20:13:20 midnight-star sudo[22733]: ppelleti : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ppelleti ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-5 minutes
Oct 14 20:13:20 midnight-star sudo[22733]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 14 20:13:30 midnight-star sudo[22733]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 14 20:13:43 midnight-star sudo[22738]: ppelleti : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ppelleti ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-5 minutes
Oct 14 20:13:43 midnight-star sudo[22738]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To `mount` a disk, you must have a pre-existing directory, a node in the filesystem that the `mount`ed filesystem will overlay.

The error message "`Mount point does not exist.`" is complaining that you don't have a pre-existing directory, or that you misspelled your mount point.

Rght Click on the filesystem's icon, open preferences, and check where it wants to mount, and ensure this directory exists.

Comment: When I right-click on "WhiteAndNerdy (nfs)", the only choices are "Open", "Open in New Tab", and "Open in New Window".  There is nothing else.

Comment: In a terminal window `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of trying to open it.

Comment: I've added the output of `journalctl` to the original question, but really there was nothing in it except the running of `journalctl` itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely related to the NFS version used on your server.
If your server allows you to enable support for multiple NFS versions, make sure v3 is enabled.
If your server only supports v4, you are out of luck, since [GVFS still doesn't support NFSv4](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/18). Nautilus uses GVFS, unlike a manual mount.
If enabling v3 and v4 still does not work for you, at least as a test, try disabling v4 (4, 4.1 and 4.2) all together.

At least up until NFS v4.1 performance does not really improve compared to using v3 [[1]](https://www.linux.com/news/benchmarking-nfsv3-vs-nfsv4-file-operation-performance/)[[2]](https://www.rootusers.com/performance-difference-between-nfs-versions/). So if you don't need the other new features introduced in v4, you might as well just stick to v3 if that solves your problem.

If you insist on using v4, you could mount the NFS share manually as a work-around:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/MyRemoteShare
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.16:RemoteShareLocation /mnt/MyRemoteShare/
```

Adapt the paths and IP address accordingly.